# allow override for path in a virtual host

Tags: apache, .htaccess

There are some PHP files on an external drive which is mapped to the Z: drive on a Windows 10 machine.  This code is in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` Apache file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>    
    DocumentRoot "Z:/files/xampp/htdocs"
    <Directory "Z:/files/xampp/htdocs">
        Options Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The task at hand is to allow `.htaccess` overrides for a file path within the path shown above.  In the `httpd.conf` file the rewrite module is enabled.  That line looks like this: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`.  I tried adding this code to the `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory "Z:/files/xampp/htdocs/miscellaneous/WebServiceExamples">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The Apache web server was stopped and restarted after making these changes. The code in `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# turn rewrite engine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# map neat URL to internal URL
RewriteRule ^mobile/list/$   RestController.php?view=all [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^mobile/show/([0-9]+)/$   RestController.php?view=single&id=$1 [nc,qsa]

</IfModule>
```

However, when a URL that should be handled by the rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` file is entered in the Chrome address bar the result is an **Object not found!  Error 404**.  Where did I go astray?

**EDIT:**
Another thing I tried was putting `httpd.conf` back to its original state, then modifying `httpd-vhosts.conf` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>    
    DocumentRoot "Z:/files/xampp/htdocs"
    <Directory "Z:/files/xampp/htdocs">
        Options Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "Z:/files/xampp/htdocs/miscellaneous/WebServiceExamples">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After stopping and restarting the Apache web server, the result is still the same as before:
**Object not found!  Error 404.**

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.  The configuration files were left in the state as described in the Edit section in the original post.  The Troubleshooting section in [this link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) was a helpful guide for determining that the configuration files were set up correctly.

This was entered as the URL in Chrome's address bar: `http://localhost:8080/miscellaneous/WebServiceExamples/SimpleRestfulWebService/mobile/list`.  Notice there is no trailing forward slash.  The rewrite rule was in `.htaccess` was written in such a way that made a trailing forward slash mandatory.  When the rewrite rule lines were modified to make the trailing slash optional, then it worked fine.  Here are the modified rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/list/?$   RestController.php?view=all [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^mobile/show/([0-9]+)/?$   RestController.php?view=single&id=$1 [nc,qsa]
```